# Entity Framework - parent has children and a reference to one child

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've got a very simple object structure ... a parent object with a number of children ... but it also has a reference to one of those children.

```
public class History
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual HistoryEvent ActiveEvent { get; set; }

    public virtual List<HistoryEvent> Events { get; set; }
}

public class HistoryEvent
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var context = new EfTest())
        {
            var history = new History
            {
                Events = new List<HistoryEvent>
                {
                    new HistoryEvent { Name = "a" },
                    new HistoryEvent { Name = "b" },
                    new HistoryEvent { Name = "c" }
                }
            };

            history.ActiveEvent = history.Events.First();

            context.History.Add(history);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

The database creates and looks how I'd expect ...

[image: Tables]

But it won't save ... the inner exception gives this ...

[image: Exception]

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to save a complex object with circular reference ,, this causes EF to be confused about which object to save first (correct me if wrong)

to solve this confusion just insert one before the other

try doing this

```
        var history = new History
        {
            Events = new List<HistoryEvent>
            {
                new HistoryEvent { Name = "a" },
                new HistoryEvent { Name = "b" },
                new HistoryEvent { Name = "c" }
            }
        };

        //history.ActiveEvent = history.Events.First();

        context.History.Add(history);
        context.SaveChanges();//now every object has an Id

        history.ActiveEvent = history.Events.First();
        context.SaveChanges();
```

if the above doesn`t work you need to change your model to include the foreign keys manually (this may help you for more control)

```
public class History
{
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
public int? ActiveEventId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("ActiveEventId")]
public virtual HistoryEvent ActiveEvent { get; set; }

public virtual List<HistoryEvent> Events { get; set; }
}
```

and same for the HistoryEvent class

```
public class HistoryEvent
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? HistoryId {get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("HistoryId ")]
    public virtual History history { get; set; }
}
```

then

1. insert history with empty history events
2. append history.Id manually to history events like

   ```
   var Events = new List<HistoryEvent> {
               new HistoryEvent { Name = "a" ,HistoryId = history.Id},
               new HistoryEvent { Name = "b" ,HistoryId = history.Id},
               new HistoryEvent { Name = "c" ,HistoryId = history.Id}
              }
   ```
3. save the events
4. get the Active eventId and update the history record

hope this helps